# What does algebraically closed field play the role in Schur's unitary triangulation theorem?

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form, unitary-matrices, matrix-analysis, schur-decomposition

Schur's unitary triangulation theorem said that

**Theorem** **(Schur’s Triangularization Theorem)** Every square complex matrix A is unitarily similar to an upper-triangular matrix, i.e., there exists a unitary matrix $U$ such that $T = U^∗AU$ is triangular.

Here, the theorem is about square complex matrix, but in the lecture, professor mentioned that any algebraically closed field matrices can fit the theorem **[with similarity instead of unitary similarity]** *(if there are mistake on the expression, it must be me misunderstanding)*.

My questions is, why algebraically closed field can work, how to connect the proof with the original square complex matrix proof?

Comment: Many results about complex numbers hold for any algebraically closed field. However, in this particular case it isn't clear to me how one would define conjugation on the field, which seems essential to the formulation.

Comment: No, I think instead of unitary similarity, we were talking about inverse similarity on the class, sorry, I will make that clear.

Comment: if you don't have any requirements on $U$ then this just follows from the Jordan decomposition (prob. a much easier proof too)

Comment: Well, the statement with similarity is basically the existence of Jordan normal form, which indeed is true for any algebraically closed field.

Answer (score 1):

suppose you are working over some algebraically closed field $\mathbb K$.  Just mimic the Schur Triangularization process, but at each stage when you complete to a basis (invertible matrix) you ignore the requirement for orthonormal columns.  The end result is
$A=STS^{-1}$
(Exactly this is walked through step by step in chapter 4 of Artin's *Algebra*.)

> how to connect the proof with the original square complex matrix
> proof?

once you have the above, if you are working over $\mathbb C$, you can run QR factorization,
$S=QR\implies A=QRTR^{-1}Q^{-1}=Q\big(RTR^{-1}\big)Q^*$
which recovers standard Schur Triangularization-- recalling that upper triangular matrices form a (semi)group.